# How to combine similar records from two dataframes in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I intend to write a code to compare if records between two dataframes match. df1 has  IDs of objects with dates when they were found  and weight of the objects sampled from df2. I want to verify if the data in df1 was correctly captured from df2.
The first dataframes is,

```r
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A5", "A8", "A15", "B11", "B35", "B36", "B45", "B50", "C2", "C3"),
DateFound = c("15/4/2020", "16/4/2020", "16/4/2020", "16/4/2020", "16/4/2021", "16/4/2021", "16/4/2021", "16/4/2021", "16/4/2021", "16/4/2021"),
Weight = c(40L, 45L, 36L, 44L, 49L, 34L, 36L, 42L, 46L, 38L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

#     ID DateFound Weight
# 1   A5 15/4/2020     40
# 2   A8 16/4/2020     45
# 3  A15 16/4/2020     36
# 4  B11 16/4/2020     44
# 5  B35 16/4/2021     49
# 6  B36 16/4/2021     34
# 7  B45 16/4/2021     36
# 8  B50 16/4/2021     42
# 9   C2 16/4/2021     46
# 10  C3 16/4/2021     38
```

The second is,

```r
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("A5", "A8", "A15", "A20", "B6", "B11", 
"B35", "B36", "B37", "B40", "B45", "B50", "C2", "C3"), X13.4.2020 = c(42L, 
45L, 38L, 34L, 39L, 46L, 34L, 44L, 39L, 35L, 39L, 55L, 51L, 55L),
X14.4.2020 = c(0L, 0L, 38L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 0L, 
50L, 0L, 0L), X15.4.2020 = c(40L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 37L, 0L, 
38L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 51L, 54L), X16.4.2020 = c(0L, 46L, 39L, 0L, 
0L, 44L, 0L, 33L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 52L, 52L, 0L), X17.4.2020 = c(NA, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 43L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 42L), X16.4.2021 = c(NA, 
NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 42L, NA, 40L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))

#     ID X13.4.2020 X14.4.2020 X15.4.2020 X16.4.2020 X17.4.2020 X16.4.2021
# 1   A5         42          0         40          0         NA         NA
# 2   A8         45          0          0         46          0         NA
# 3  A15         38         38          0         39          0          0
# ...
```

The intended output as shown below: it adds a column of the object weights from df2 for the same date recorded in df1.

```
df1_2output_

#     ID DateFound Weight df2
# 1   A5 15/4/2020     40  40
# 2   A8 16/4/2020     45  46
# 3  A15 16/4/2020     36  39
# 4  B11 16/4/2020     44  44
# 5  B35 16/4/2021     49   0
# 6  B36 16/4/2021     34  33
# 7  B45 16/4/2021     36   0
# 8  B50 16/4/2021     42  42
# 9   C2 16/4/2021     46  NA
# 10  C3  1/4/2021     38  40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `df2` is of wide format with dates as column names, so you need to transform it to long and convert those dates to the standard date format.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(DateFound = as.Date(DateFound, '%d/%m/%Y')) %>%
  left_join(
    df2 %>% pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = 'DateFound', values_to = 'Weight',
                         names_transform = list(DateFound = ~ as.Date(.x, 'X%d.%m.%Y'))),
    by = c('ID', 'DateFound')
  )

    ID  DateFound Weight.x Weight.y
1   A5 2020-04-15       40       40
2   A8 2020-04-16       45       46
3  A15 2020-04-16       36       39
4  B11 2020-04-16       44       44
5  B35 2021-04-16       49        0
6  B36 2021-04-16       34        0
7  B45 2021-04-16       36        0
8  B50 2021-04-16       42       42
9   C2 2021-04-16       46       NA
10  C3 2021-04-16       38       40
```